# What factors does Delphi activation take into account in deciding whether I need to request a bump of my permitted install count

Tags: delphi

I installed XE4 in a Windows7 VM under VMWare.

My question is, what aspects of the VM does the Delphi protection system take into account in deciding whether I have consumed (another) one of my permitted installs?  I imagine that it takes notice of the VM name and the user account name in the VM, but are those correct and are there any others?

I'm asking because inter alia I don't want to find that tinkering with the VM's set-up exhausts my permitted installs (and the fact that I *may* be able to get the count increased while Embarcadero is still in business is no guarantee that I *will* be able to at some arbitrary point in the future).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor licensing related issue and not a programming related question. It should be asked in the vendor's own support forums instead. It's highly likely to prompt a discussion of the licensing practices of the software vendor, which is inappropriate here.

Comment: Ken, fair comment I guess.  I wasn't intending to provoke a debate about EMB's *policy*, which has been done to death in their NGs, I was just wanting to get at the facts regarding its implementation.  Otoh, I've resisted the temptation to reply Bruce's remark about my concern being a red herring, which would have proved your point <g> if I hadn't.

Comment: Questions about programming tools are [specifically on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, @Ken. A question about the license rules should only prompt a *discussion* of licensing practices if people start talking about what they think the licensing practices *should* be instead of sticking to what they *are*. The question asks for the latter. We should vote down or edit away the former because *that* would be off-topic.

Comment: I know about the "to death in their NGs", which is why I fear it will happen here as well. :-) As far as its implementation details, that would seem to be something only EMBT would be aware of, don't you think? I'm not sure how anyone here can definitively answer that question except an EMBT employee, who probably can't discuss it. (I agree with Bruce's remark, but in fairness to him you *did* start it with the "while Embarcadero is still in business", which implies that there's a fear that won't be the case (also known as "FUD").)

Comment: @Rob: I beg to differ. Software licensing questions are on-topic for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), according to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165980/172661), not SO. This question is also about the vendor's internal implementation of that licensing, which again is not something that can be reasonably expected to be answered here.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me whether that question is talking about licenses issued *by* us to our customers for using our software, or about licenses issued *to* us for software-development tools we use, @Ken. Questions can be appropriate in multiple places. As I said before, questions about software tools used by programmers are on-topic here. Activation requirements of Delphi are a subset of that.

Comment: @Rob: But this isn't about that-it's about the *internal implementation details of that activation*, which no one outside EMBT would know, and those employees are apparently prohibited from discussing it (or it would have been done already in their own forums). But fair enough; I guess we'll just have to disagree here. :-)