# Reinstalling Windows without re-registering Delphi

Tags: delphi, reinstall

I'll be reinstalling Windows and I wondered if there's a way to backup/restore Delphi license info so I don't "lose" one of my installations for that.

In other words - is there a way to uninstall Delphi, reinstall Windows, reinstall Delphi without that being treated as a "new" installation?

[I want to completely wipe out my computer and start out from scratch. I'll be reinstalling XE5, XE7, and 10 Seattle.]

Comment: I don't think you have anything to worry about. If you hit the limit you can get it raised. I've done some a number of times.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, you can bump the limit, but you have to wait for their working hours. And holidays at at the door. Plus with above versions there is no grace period. If you reinstall and you figure out that you need bump you are stuck until you get it.

Comment: I think best would be if you can submit license bump request ASAP stating what you need to do. If they are still working today, you may get lucky.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, I just wondered if there's a better way that I don't know about.

Comment: There is the Embarcadero License Management tool. It's LicenseManager.exe in the bin directory. That has an action to delete licenses. No idea whether or not that reduces the count. I doubt it. If I were you I would do this all in the new year.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is no mechanism for reducing license count.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar If you know that, then you can answer such

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The only possible solution would be backing up license slips and using those after reinstallation on same computer. Problem is I don't know if that would work, because I have never tried, and I don't know to what properties of the system is license exactly tied to.

Comment: I know that changing computer name invalidates the license. Obviously, it is tied to some hardware properties, too. What else, I don't know. I also know that upgrading my computer from 8.1 to Windows 10, didn't invalidate my Delphi 7, and XE4 license.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You mean just the .slip file? Can try. Computer name will not change, nor will the OS version.

Comment: @gabr Why don't you ask Emba?

Comment: Yep, the slip file is all you need. But slip may be connected to some other data Windows can mesh up during reinstallation. If you are wiling to take the chance, you can give it a try. But only folks from Embarcadero could give you definitive answer. Why don't you ping Marco Cantu. He was responding to G+ forum earlier today.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The .slip files used for registration info are in *C:\ProgramData*, in either the *CodeGear* or *Embarcadero* folders depending on which version of the IDE you're using.

I've successfully copied the files from these folders to a thumb drive and moved them to a new computer. Note that part of the registration information is the local computer name, so in order to work on a different machine (or a clean Windows install on the same machine) the computer name needs to stay the same. Just name the computer the same, copy the .slip files to the same location on the new machine, and then install Delphi/RAD Studio.

To be on the safe side, I always copy the entire folder (including all subfolders and their contents) to make sure I've gotten everything the IDE needs.

Comment: I'd expect the machine signature to use more than just the machine name.

Comment: @David: I've gone from a Dell with a 125GB drive, 2GB RAM to a Gateway with a 250GB drive and 8GB RAM without an issue, and I've changed from an Asus laptop (250GB/4)  to a Gateway (1TB/8GB) without an issue, as long as the machine names all stayed the same. If they are using something other than machine name, it's pretty flexible. (I've not reregistered D2007 in the past 8 years, and I've changed PCs and laptops every 3 years at my job.) So expect whatever you want; I can only tell you what has worked successfully for me for years.

Comment: I've also used an Acronis image to upgrade the hard disk in a laptop (from 500GB to 1TB) by creating the image on the new drive, shutting down, removing the old drive and installing the new one, and rebooting (which clearly would change any disk related machine signature) without issue.

Comment: Of course, Emba do allow you to install on multiple machines before they object. I've done that a plenty and only rarely asked for a bump. I would think that only Emba know how the system works.

Comment: @David: I never claimed to know how EMBT's system works. I can only speak from my (multiple) successes in using this method with all versions of Delphi up to XE8 (I've not replaced a machine since Seattle was released, but its install contains the same filetypes as the others, so I'd expect it to work the same there.) Go and move your Delphi installs to a half dozen different systems using the info I provided (as I've actually done), and if any fail then you can discuss the issues with my answer. I'm quite certain Gabr is capable of deciding whether he wants to use the info or not.

Comment: If I can see 10 white sheep, is it reasonable to claim that all sheep are white? That's my point.

Comment: @David: You've not made a point, other than that you can create noise and clutter regarding a topic of which you have no knowledge. If you don't want to use this information, please feel free not to do so. Gabr is extremely knowledgeable (considerably more than either of us), and I trust he can assess whether he wants to use the information or not. The worst outcome is that the IDE would need to be registered again and EMBT would need to bump a limit for him, of which he is clearly aware.

Comment: @KenWhite:  Did you always install using the same user account name on your various machines?  I recall an EMBA NG thread that recorded users' observations of what requires a new activation and using a different machine name was certainly one of them, but I've a vague recollection that the user name was mentioned, too.

Comment: @Martyn: No, actually not. We went from a Novell Netware network to a Windows Server 2000 network to a Windows Server 2003 Active Domain network during the process, so there were three separate user names and user accounts during that time. (It went from my first name (Netware) to my three initials (Win2K) to themy three initials followed by two digits (the AD domain is roughly 12K users in various OUs, so initials alone weren't enough). The only consistency was the computer name, which for internal reasons has remained the same since I was given my first PC there 12 years ago.

Comment: I made a point. In my first comment. A signature based solely on machine name would seem odd. Very easy to subvert. Or do you disagree. It's not as if you presented any evidence to contradict. That you've reinstalled many times means nothing. I've done likewise many times on different machines. I have my mainstream Delphi installed on 3 machines right now. All with different names. I'd expect something authoritative in an answer here.

Comment: @David: And yet it works. Repeatedly, for several years. On several different machines. With the initial startup of Delphi on each machine showing *Registered* in the splash screen. As for *authoritative*, the question doesn't ask for someone at EMBT to answer (which would be the only authoritative one), in which case the question belongs at EMBT support. Instead, it was posted here, at a public site, asking the general user base. As I said, if you don't want to use the information, feel free not to do so. Other readers can as well. I've pointed out that this was based on *my own experience*.

Comment: I can't follow your logic. Your deductive step is akin to, I can see 10 white sheep, ergo all sheep are white. Also, how do you explain installing onto multiple machines with different names. For all you know you've just not hit the limit. But perhaps you are right. I don't know. I'd just like to see some actual evidence. The "all sheep are white" argument is fallacious.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Ironically, one of my very first qs on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135038/what-factors-does-delphi-activation-take-into-account - got closed as "not about programming" but the limited empirical evidence I've come across personally is consistent with what Ken says in his answer, and google finds numerous thread comments that the activation isn't tied to hardware, e.g. MAC address.  And, like Ken said in a comment to my q, those who know definitively aren't likely to reveal it.

Comment: @MartynA So how come I can install on multiple machines with different names?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I'm not saying you can't.  But does your "multiple machines" keep you below the reputed permissible 3 activations for a given Delphi version (and licence key)?

Comment: @Martyn I've gone over 3 I believe. I think only Emba know the details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Diferent Delphi versions came with different license count. I believe it is 3 now. Also how did you register? Unless you successfully used same slip file on different computers you have no way of knowing how was that license activation counted.

Comment: @David: I didn't hit the limit **because I only installed once**. There was no attempt to register a second time. I don't understand your lapse in comprehension here. If you cross the street in front of your house to enter your office on the other side of the street, and you do it 5 days a week for a full year and make it safely, certainly it's possible that on the next day you'll get hit by a bus, but that doesn't make every one of the past crossings impossible. Your argument about sheep is simply nonsense. If you don't like the information in the answer, **don't use it**.

Comment: So it would be fine to install with one licence onto 10 machines if they all had the same name? Indeed unlimited machines with the same name? For all versions of Delphi? The argument about proof is not nonsense at all. I am confident in my training as a pure mathematician. I do understand the methods of mathematical proof. "I've done this a few times and it worked, therefore it always works" is not a valid argument. I'm not saying that you are right or wrong, only that you have not offered any evidence.

Comment: @David: Once again, your lack of comprehension here is astounding. I didn't say **anywhere** that *it always works*. I've said I've used this technique to move my Delphi license from one machine to a new machine multiple times with success, and that it **hasn't yet failed**. No where did I say it was guaranteed to work, and I previously mentioned that if it failed the only risk was actually having to re-register (with the potential need to get EMBT to bump the count). I don't know how much more clearly I can state it. Perhaps *reading comprehension* should be your next field of study.

Comment: David, Ken:  I don't doubt you are both convinced you are right.  Surely, the rightness or not of your positions depends on what the EMB activation algorithm counts as "an install", theories about which can only be disproved by counter-example, not proved.  I have to say that Ken's position, if I understand correctly, that he's only ever done one "install" squares with my own experience, even though it jars somewhat with the intuition that an install ought to be tied to something a bit more restrictive than a machine name.

Comment: If Embarcadero would invalidate the license every time something changes into the computer (ram and other hardware, username, etc) then they will have to hire lots of people because they will get hit by lots of new key requests. It makes sense to be more lenient related to how quick to invalidate the license.

Comment: @KenWhite For me it works between Dell Vostro (Windows 7) -> Dell Latitude (Windows 10). THANK YOU.

Comment: This is an old thread. But I would add, I have changed CPU, RAM, HDD (never CPU) on my dev computer(s) many times and it never invalidated my Delphi license. But I changed my machine name yesterday, and when I launched Delphi, it made me re-enter the license key, and unfortunately it said I had used all attempts, so I had to get Embd to bump my license count, which I have done every year for as long as I can remember. It would be helpful for Embd to have a license reset mechanism (like a password reset) that I can do without having to wait until the next business day for them to bump it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when renaming my Windows 10 computer. Apparently the license is bound to the computer name. I had to re-register Delphi after renaming my computer but failed because of the limit of my license key.
Solution was renaming back my computer and renaming C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\.cgb_license.corrupted and C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\.licenses\.cg_license.corrupted to files without the .corrupted as suffix. My licence slip file was C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\.2016_2.#############.slip.